# Let $f \in M^{1,1} (\mathbb R)$ (Feichtinger's algebra /Modulation Space). Can we say $Fof\in M^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$; $F$ is an entire function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-algebras, fourier-transform

The [Modulation space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_space) ( Feichtinger's algebra),

$$S_{0} (\mathbb R) = M^{1, 1}(\mathbb R): = \{ f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R) : V_{g}(f) \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^{2}) \};$$

where $V_{g}f (x, w)$ is the short- time Fourier transform of $f$ with respect to window $g\in S(\mathbb R)$ = [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)  defined by
 $$V_{g}f (x, w) = <f, M_{w}T_{x}g>= \int_{\mathbb R}f(t)\overline{g(t-x)} e^{-2\pi i w\cdot t }dt.$$

Examples: (1) $S(\mathbb R) \subset M^{1, 1} (\mathbb R) \subset L^{1}(\mathbb R)\cap C_{0}(\mathbb R)\cap  \widehat {L^{1}(\mathbb R)} .$ (2) Define the triangle function $f(x)= 1-|x|;$ for  $|x|<1$ and $f(x)= 0; $ for $|x|\geq 0$. Then $f \in M^{1, 1} (\mathbb R)$ (Note that, $\hat{f}(t) = (\frac{\sin \pi t }{t})^{2};  t\not = 0$).

Properties: (1) $V_{g}f(x,w) = <\hat {f}, T_{w}M_{-x}\hat {g}> = e^{-2\pi i x \cdot w }V_{\hat {g}}\hat {f} (w, -x)$; (2) So, $M^{1,1 } (\mathbb R)$  is invariant under the Fourier transform; (3) If $f, g \in M^{1,1 } (\mathbb R) $ then $fg \in M^{1,1 } (\mathbb R)$; (4) $M^{1,1} (\mathbb R)$ is an Banach algebra under point wise multiplication.

By above property (4), Given $f \in M^{1,1} (\mathbb R)$; then $P_{n}(f)$ (polynomial of degree $n$) is again a member of $M^{1,1} (\mathbb R)$.

**My question is**: Let $f\in M^{1,1} (\mathbb R)$; and consider the power series $P(f (t) ) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (f(t))^{n} $ , which convergent and converges uniformly on a compact subsets of $\mathbb C$, and assume p(0)=0(to avoiding some trivial cases, like exponetial).

Can we expect $P(f(t)) \in M^{1,1 } (\mathbb R)$ ;
or we can produce counter example ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $M^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$ is a Banach algebra, $P(f(t))$ is in $M^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$ whenever $\|f\|_{M^{1,1}}$ is smaller than the radius of convergence of the series $P$. Here you have to use a sub-multiplicative norm $\|\;\|_{M^{1,1}}$. On a Banach algebra you can always change to an equivalent sub-multiplicative norm.